# SwiftUI List Rows Not Refreshed After Updating Binding In Other Screen

Tags: ios, swift, state, swiftui, watchos

I have a simple watchOS SwiftUI Application. The application has three screens. The first screen consists of a `List` of items. When you press that item, it will redirect to another screen & when you tap a button there it will open up a `.sheet` `View` which allows you to edit the item in the list.

The first view looks like this:

```
class Object: NSObject {

    var title: String

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }

}

struct Row: View {

    @Binding var object: Object

    var body: some View {
        Text(self.object.title)
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var objects = [Object]()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(objects.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                    NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(object: self.$objects[idx])) {
                        Row(object: self.$objects[idx])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.objects = [
                Object(title: "Test 1"),
                Object(title: "Test 2")
            ]
        }
    }

}
```

These are the second & third views:

```
struct SecondView: View {

    @Binding var object: Object
    @State private var showPicker: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(object.title)
            Button(action: {
                self.showPicker.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Press Here")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPicker) {
            ThirdView(object: self.$object)
        }
    }

}
```

```
struct ThirdView: View {

    @Binding var object: Object

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(object.title)
            Button(action: {
                self.update()
            }, label: {
                Text("Tap here")
            })
        }
    }

    func update() {
        let newObj = self.object
        newObj.title = "Hello, World!"
        self.object = newObj
    }

}
```

I'd expect, whenever I tap the button in the third view, the `Binding` (and thus the `State`) get's updated with "Hello, World". However, that is not the case, although not immediately.

What I currently see happening is that when I tap the button in the third view, the `Text` in that view does not get updated. When I dismiss the third view and go back to the second view, I do see "Hello, World". But when I go back to the list, the row still has the old value.

One other thing I noticed is that, when I fill the array of objects directly, like so:

```
@State private var objects = [Object(title: "Test 1"), Object(title: "Test 2")]
```

and remove the filling of the array in `.onAppear`, this work totally how I'd expect it to (everything updates immediately to "Hello, World".

Does anyone one know what I'm doing wrong here or did I might hit a bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Complex objects need to be classes conforming to `@ObservableObject`.
Observed ivars need to be published.

```
class Object: ObservableObject {
  @Published var title: String
  [...]
}
```

Observing views would use them as `@ObservedObject`

```
struct Row: View {
  @ObservedObject var object: Object
  [...]
}
```

You might have to create an object wrapper for your lists

```
class ObjectList: ObservableObject {
  @Published var objects: [Object]
  [...]
}
```